# Basic Complex Analysis Questions

Tags: complex-analysis

A few quick questions from an older text on complex analysis:

$|e^{it}|^2=e^{it}\cdot\overline{e^{it}}=e^{it}\cdot e^{-it}$

I'm not sure about the notation $|e^{it}|^2$, but I'm assuming it indicates the magnitude of the vector squared?  If so, I'm having trouble getting to the next part, $e^{it}\cdot\overline{e^{it}}$, which seems to be $e^{it}$ times its complex conjugate?

A separate question, this line of reasoning: if $z=x + iy$ then $e^z=e^xe^{iy}$ and therefore $|e^z|=e^x.$

Can't grok how that follows.

Text: Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, 1970, p. 3

Comment: It is just $|z|^2 = z*\bar{z}$, nothing extraordinary or tricky.

Comment: If $y\in\mathbb R$, then $\lvert e^{iy}\rvert=1$

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, note that
$\displaystyle |z \times w| = |z| \times |w|, ~: ~z,w \in \Bbb{C}.$

The above result may be manually verified by setting 
$\displaystyle z = (x + iy), w = (u + iv)$

and then comparing 
$\displaystyle |~(x + iy)(u + iv)~|$ with
$\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \times \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}.$

Further, as indicated by the answer of José Carlos Santos, any complex number of the form $e^{i\theta}$ is *some element* of the unit circle.

Therefore, for all $\displaystyle \theta, ~|e^{i\theta}| = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

If $z\in\Bbb C$, and if $a,b\in\Bbb R$ are such that $z=a+bi$, then\begin{align}z\cdot\overline z&=(a+bi)(a-bi)\\&=a^2+b^2\\&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}^2\\&=|z|^2.\end{align}

Besides, if $y\in\Bbb R$, then\begin{align}|e^{yi}|&=|cos(y)+\sin(y)i|\\&=\cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y)\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Given $z=x+iy$ we have that $z \overline{z} = (x+yi)(x-yi)=x^2 + xyi - xyi -(yi)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ which is the magnitude squared.